# DSE Cassandra decimal type

Tags: cassandra, solr

I generated solrschema with `dsetool` on a table name `seriesdata` (its key is composed by `seriesmetadata_id`, `initialtime`; two decimal field).
These fields are defined as `DecimalStrField` but they are numeric valued (I have to execute range selection). I tried to change schema defining these fields as:

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieLongField" name="TrieLongField"/>
```

but I receive this error:

> [cassandra@bigdatalin-03 ~]$ dsetool reload_core timeseriesks.seriesdata schema=schema_data.xml solrconfig=solr_config_data.xml reindex=true -l cassandra -p cassandra
>       org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.CassandraIndexSchema$ValidationException: Mismatch between Solr key field [seriesmetadata_id] with type {TrieLongField{class=org.apache.solr.schema.TrieLongField,analyzer=org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer,args={class=org.apache.solr.schema.TrieLongField}}] and Cassandra key alias [seriesmetadata_id] with type [decimal]
>               at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:665)
>               at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:303)
>               at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:294)
>               at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.createOrReloadCore(SearchDseToolCommands.java:559)
>               at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands.access$200(SearchDseToolCommands.java:59)
>               at com.datastax.bdp.tools.SearchDseToolCommands$ReloadCore.execute(SearchDseToolCommands.java:209)
>               at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:126)
>               at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.run(DseTool.java:51)
>               at com.datastax.bdp.tools.DseTool.main(DseTool.java:186)

Why?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Datastax Enterprise search nodes, solr is integrated with cassandra. What has happened here is that when you changed your solr schema, you did not change the associated cassandra schema. The error message is telling you that there is a mismatch between your new solr schema and the cassandra schema for the same table. Check the cassandra schema for `seriesdata` and make it consistent with the solr schema.

Comment: I changed the type of cassandra table from decimal to bigint and it works.Thansk